# Python3 - Updating a 'power' variable in an inner loop modifies the outer loop's aggreggation variable

Tags: python

I read through all the files in a directory (csv files) - I ignore the first 7 'header ' lines of each, then find the time and power values from line 8 to line 151. Each of the lines I read is of the form [example lines 6-9 & 46-48]

```
Time;Power
HH:mm;kW
00:10;0.000
00:20;0.000
<snip>
06:20;0.012
06:30;0.042
06:40;0.060
```

My code successfully ignores all the post-midnight readings of zero and correctly identifies the first non-zero power reading at 06:20. It uses the time (hours and minutes) to a adjust a variable that contains the timestamp for the day and stores the now hour/minute inclusive timestamp and the power in a complex variable `timePower[(timestamp),(power)]`
It then appends the variable `timePower[(),()]` to the variable `dayPower[]` and starts again for the next line of the file.

For a reason I cannot work out, the next line parses fine until the point at which I update `timePower[0]` with the new timestamp and `timePower[1]` with the new power - updating these variables seems to also update the existing entry in the `dayPower[]` variable (`dayPower[0]`), now, right before I'm about to append a new entry, the old entry looks the same as the new one. The new line successfully appends. This errant behaviour repeats until I've finished reading all the non-zero values and all lines in `dayPower[]` look the same as the final entry. The relevant function is listed below:

```
def parse_power_values(path, filename, theDate):
  timePower = [(),()] #a list that will be assigned two items; the timestamp and the power for that timeslot
  dayPower = [] # A list that will have all the timePowers for the day appended
  currentFile = open(path + filename,'r')
  for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
    if i <= 7:
      doingSomething = True
      #print 'header' + str(i) + '/ ' + line.rstrip()
    elif ((i > 7) and (i <= 151)):
      lineParts = line.split(';')
      theTime = lineParts[0].split(':')
      theHour = theTime[0]
      theMin = theTime[1]
      timestamp = theDate.replace(hour=int(theHour),minute=int(theMin)) #theDate is a timestamp obj with the current date but hour & minute at 00:00 to start with.
      power = lineParts[1].rstrip()
      if power == '-.---':
        power = 0.000
      if (float(power) > 0):
        #append_to_database(con, timestamp,power)
        timePower[0] = timestamp
        timePower[1] = power
        dayPower.append(timePower)
    elif i > 151:
     return dayPower
     #break
  currentFile.close()
```

Comment: `dayPower.append(timePower)` doesn't make a copy of anything; every time this line is executed, another reference to the *same*, singular `timePower` list gets added to the `dayPower` list.  All of those references will necessarily show the same contents.  I don't see any reason for `timePower` to exist; `dayPower.append([timestamp, power])` looks like it would do the job, appending a brand-new list each time.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper. The intent is that for each line that's read timePower is updated with that line's values for timestamp and power then timePower (with it's instance values) is appended to the dayPower list. Then the next line is read and the timePower variable is reused with the new line's values. This is then appended to dayPower and so-on! You may be right that I could do without timePower but why doesn't my logic work?

Comment: Again, you are appending *the same list* every single time.  Every reference to that list will show the same contents, because there's only one list to *have* contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@jasonharper was right and my modified function now looks like this:

```
def parse_power_values(path, filename, theDate):
  # timePower = [(),()] #a list that will be assigned two items; the timestamp and the power for that timeslot
  dayPower = [] # A list that will have all the timePowers for the day appended
  currentFile = open(path + filename,'r')
  for i, line in enumerate(currentFile):
    if i <= 7:
      doingSomething = True
      #print 'header' + str(i) + '/ ' + line.rstrip()
    elif ((i > 7) and (i <= 151)):
      lineParts = line.split(';')
      theTime = lineParts[0].split(':')
      theHour = theTime[0]
      theMin = theTime[1]
      timestamp = theDate.replace(hour=int(theHour),minute=int(theMin))
      power = lineParts[1].rstrip()
      if power == '-.---':
        power = 0.000
      if (float(power) > 0):
        dayPower.append([timestamp,power])
    elif i > 151:
     return dayPower
     #break
  currentFile.close()
```